# How can I make my App appear in Play Store?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I had uploaded an app on play store and it is published and live. But it is not appeared in play store neither i found by name or keywords even all the related app appear. My app appear by only generated links [Secure Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.securesearch) or package name.

So Please help me guys to appear my app in search of keywords either it will appear low in search results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question about an application store, rather than a programming question.  See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need some Downloads...
Make your NEW users search and click on the app.
Because there are other apps out there that do the same thing.
Just wait for a little bit.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English